# Inexplicably slow execution before reboot and recompilation

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, darwin

I know that this question might be too broad without more specific information, but I don't know how to handle this problem.

I have a code (console application) written in C++11 and I build it with cmake. I noticed that sometimes after minor changes and recompilation it becomes about three times slower than it used to, and it does not matter what I do, it works very slow. Even if I redo the changes. After a reboot the same executable still runs slow, BUT after recompilation it becomes fast again.

It happened to me at least three or four times. What could cause such a weird behaviour?

I use cmake 3.5 with clang on Darwin17.

**Edit:**

- Slow executables (3.3mb) are about twice as big as the fast ones (1.5mb).
- CMakeLists.txt has not changed and no debugger mode used.

Comment: Do you have a build script randomly selecting optimization levels? :-).

Comment: Have you compared the executables files, are they the same before and after recompilation?

Comment: Sounds like antivirus in play. Or maybe virus in play.

Comment: I excavated previous versions from Dropbox. It is surprising that the slow versions are about twice as big (3.3mb) as the fast ones (1.5mb)

Comment: Sounds like debug versus release builds

Comment: Nothing is changed in CMakeLists.txt, I always build release.

Comment: Try to use `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE TRUE)` and see what exact command line flags you are using.

Comment: You haven't even explained _what_ is slow in your program. You have to provide some reproducible example or _at least_ explain _what_ is slow and how you timed it. Until then it will only be guesswork

Comment: It's a simulation tool that performs lot of tensor and vector multiplication and neighbour searching. I measured the execution time with clock_t, however, it is quite noticeable without any measurement. It takes about three minutes to finish instead of one.

Comment: I've found situations where running my app under the debugger slows it down. Specifically, I have a utility app that will max-out my processors (dual 6-core CPUs w/hyperthreading, or 24 concurrent threads) when executed from the command-line. But that same (exact) binary, when run from Xcode (debugger attached) rarely uses more than 6 or 7 threads. Most apps run just fine, but a few do this and I don't know why.